# How to resolve “Value below was evaluated just now.” for chained then functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am using `https://pokeapi.co/` API to fetch all pokemon. I am trying to iterate through each pokemon list https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=44 and get the data. I am using promise for this. But my promise is returning me`“Value below was evaluated just now”`.

I have already tried workaround for this:-

```
1. JSON.stringify().
2. JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())
3. setTimeout
4. map, concat etc.

var getPokemonList = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=4");
    xhr.onload = () => resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
    xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);
    xhr.send();
});

var getPokemonListDetails = getPokemonList
    .then(function (fulfilledList) {
        console.log(fulfilledList.results);
        var pokemonList = [];
        setTimeout(() => {
            fulfilledList.results.forEach(function (pokemon) {
                const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("GET", pokemon.url);
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                        pokemonList.push(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                    }
                };
                xhr.send();
            });
        }, 3000); 
        return pokemonList;
    })
    .then(function (fulfilledListDetails) {
        console.log(fulfilledListDetails);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    });
```

The above code giving me “Value below was evaluated just now” array data. What I can do to make it usable.

Comment: You already made it right for the first request (wrapping it into a promise) why don't you do that for the other ones too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly used a Pomise to wrap the first API call, however you did not wrap the timer and the other API calls, therefore the promise resolves before they are done.
Modern browsers support `fetch()` which is way easier to use than `XMLHttpRequest`, and it already returns a Promise which can easily be chained. Now the only thing thats left is to wrap the timeout:

```
 const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
```

Now that we have all these Promises, `Promise.all` and chaining can be used to combine them:

```
 const pokemonList = fetch(  "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=4" ).then(res => res.json());

 const pokemonDetails = pokemonList.then(list => {
   return delay(3000).then(() => {
     return Promise.all(list.results.map(pokemon => {
       return fetch(pokemon.url).then(res => res.json());
    });
  });
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function getPokemonList(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=4");
    xhr.onload = () => resolve(xhr.responseText);
    xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);
    xhr.send();
  }).then(function(data){
    //Do whatever with data
}).catch(function(error){
    //Handle error
});
```

Source:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: How is that different from the code the OP has shown?